# How to use buttons in codenameone

Tags: java, codenameone, hybrid-mobile-app

Can you tell me how to move from one page to another on button click which I made using GUI builder. I was using android studio for the last three months when I moved to Codenameone everything seems so different

Answer (score 0):

In the GUI builder:

- Select the button
- Select "Events"
- "Action Listener"

Go to the code you should see a method name matching your action listener.

In the callback code write something like this:

```
new OtherForm().show();
```